# How do I transfer funds to another account from a lightwallet.dat file

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, wallet-transfer, light-clients

I have a lightwallet.dat file which I exported from [ujomusic.com](https://alpha.ujomusic.com/#/imogen_heap/tiny_human/tiny_human). It's in a different format to that used by geth. I don't expect geth will import it so can I create an account with the same number as that account, and using the private key somehow, transfer the funds to another account? This is so that I can get at the Ether in the account.

Can I retrieve the plaintext private key? If so, how do I do that?

The file looks like this:

```
{
    "encSeed":
{         "encStr":"U2FsdGVkX186DSL2uPp1vZO......","iv":"1cb31568e......","salt":"3a0d...."},
    "encHdRootPriv":    {"encStr":"U2FsdGVkX19FA0tZsR......","iv":"da5e226....","salt":"45034...."},
"hdIndex":1,
"encPrivKeys":{
"92f2f6b0cc1.......:{"key":"U2FsdGVkX183.....","iv":"5ec1968....","salt":"371302....."}},
"addresses":["0x92f2f6b......"],"keyHash":"f1af35a6222......",
"salt":{"words":[-918769374,1616628770,1822257817,983741528],"sigBytes":16}}
```

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking. what is a lightwallet.dat and what has it to do with ujomusic 'tiny human' with such heavy javascript that my browser tends to die?

Comment: I'm preparing/trying an answer specifically for the ujomusic lightwallet; I think question title can be improved by being more specific, because the fundamental answer to the general question is "Yes".

Comment: I've reworded the title so it matches the specific detail in the question. I'll ask the general question as a separate one because I think it's useful to know too. Anyone seeing this - please vote for reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on an answer by user @Clovis:

```
npm install eth-lightwallet
node
>var lightwallet = require("eth-lightwallet")
>var upgrade = require("eth-lightwallet/lib/upgrade")
>var jsonStr='contents of ./app/users/admin/*.json file'
>var newJSON
>upgrade.upgradeOldSerialized(jsonStr, , function(err, tmpJSON) {newJSON=tmpJSON;console.log(newJSON);});
>keystore = lightwallet.keystore.deserialize(newJSON);
>var derivedKey;
>lightwallet.keystore.deriveKeyFromPasswordAndSalt('', '', function (err, pwDerivedKey) {derivedKey = pwDerivedKey;});
>var addresses = keystore.getAddresses();
>keystore.exportPrivateKey(addresses[0], derivedKey);
```

---

### OLD answer

Ujo uses [Lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet).  Exporting from Lightwallet and then importing to Geth should help access the funds.  (An alternative is to continue using Lightwallet APIs.)

**Export from Lightwallet**

In the directory where your lightwallet.dat is, run the following commands: obviously you need to **use your own Ujo address and password**.  This assumes your system already has [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org).

```
npm install eth-lightwallet

node

> var lightwallet = require('eth-lightwallet')

> newJSON = lightwallet.keystore.upgradeOldSerialized(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('lightwallet.dat')), <password>)

> keystore = lightwallet.keystore.deserialize(newJSON)

> keystore.exportPrivateKey(<address>, <password>)
'7...bla'
```

In this example 7...bla is the private key.  (I have omitted the output of the other commands above so that it's clearer.)

**Import to Geth**

Copy the private key

Paste the key in a text file, let's say must_delete_this.txt and import it with geth:

`geth account import must_delete_this.txt`

delete the file named must_delete_this.txt

Comment: The APIs have changed since this was written and the accepted answer to this question is better: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/where-to-find-the-private-key-for-my-contract-in-blockapps

Comment: Thanks, I tried editing as well as use `deriveKeyFromPasswordAndSalt` per your comment...

Answer (score 1):

If you have the private key available, simply save it in a text file, let's say `damn_private_key` and import it with geth:

```
geth account import /path/to/damn_private_key
```

More [details](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/466/87). Don't forget to delete the plain private key file on your disk.