# Where to find the private key for my contract in blockapps?

Tags: contract-deployment, private-key, javascript

I am trying to use blockapps-js to invoke functions on my smart contract deployed in blockapps. Since I need the private key for it, I am looking at the app/users/admin/.json file. Problem is I cannot figure out which of these fields to use. Is it encPrivKeys.key? My code is not working yet, and am trying to figure out whether that is the cause.

```
{
  "encSeed": {
    "encStr": "...",
    "iv": "...",
    "salt": "..."
  },
  "encHdRootPriv": {
    "encStr": "...",
    "iv": "",
    "salt": ""
  },
  "hdIndex": 1,
  "encPrivKeys": {
    "": {
    "key": "...",
    "iv": "",
    "salt": ""
  }
},
  "addresses": ["..."],
  "keyHash": "...",
  "salt": {
    "words": [, -,,],
    "sigBytes": 16
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, not sure if it's the best way of doing it, but I finally made it happen.

Here is how:

```
npm install eth-lightwallet
node
>var lightwallet = require("eth-lightwallet")
>var upgrade = require("eth-lightwallet/lib/upgrade")
>var jsonStr='contents of ./app/users/admin/*.json file'
>var newJSON
>upgrade.upgradeOldSerialized(jsonStr, , function(err, tmpJSON) {newJSON=tmpJSON;console.log(newJSON);});
>keystore = lightwallet.keystore.deserialize(newJSON);
>var derivedKey;
>lightwallet.keystore.deriveKeyFromPassword('', function (err, pwDerivedKey) {derivedKey = pwDerivedKey;});
>var addresses = keystore.getAddresses();
>keystore.exportPrivateKey(addresses[0], derivedKey);
```

I used advice from [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/630/how-do-i-transfer-funds-to-another-account-from-a-lightwallet-dat-file), however, sdk-s have changed since.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, then feel free to mark it as correct.

Comment: In the version I installed today the deriveKeyFromPassword function doesn't exist, and there is deriveKeyFromPasswordAndSalt. However the salt argument is optional.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with blockapps, but encprivkey is going to be your encrypted private key. The key is encrypted by the `iv (hash)` field and then salted with the salt field.

You will need to decrypt the private key before you can use it. ;)