# Is it possible to *write* (not print) a paper wallet without having to copy a big JSON?

Tags: private-key, cold-storage, backup, paper-wallets, brain-wallets

In Bitcoin, you can store a paper wallet by merely writing down the private key of an address, which is very small. You can also write ~20 words generated from that address, if you want. In Ethereum, in order to backup an account, I was suggested to copy a file on my keychain directory (OSX). The issue is, that file is a moderately big JSON. Writing all that in a paper is very error prone.

Is it possible to generate a small set of words, or just a hex private key, that I can write down in a paper and restore later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can simply generate pairs of unencrypted or encrypted private and public keys. For example, use this [bulk key generator](https://ryepdx.github.io/ethaddress.org/#/bulkWallets):

```
1,"0xb7d3a6d96960c2e9650822be7c1cc4ebe8bb3718","9a130892d949ab5faf678ac6295d3ab05a434448b824c0dc43bf86a4c2bbf747"
2,"0xbf3407c1231b3612dc6d2da07f32208ed1e17ebd","e9a1bc1d7e5a815499009cf94139b3a4f532b0530df737247b6a0eccb65e5384"
3,"0x7637dc580f362786cbdc9e59a1baa9db4b46aa38","d7c8c4735ac5d665b7d9dd4a4d3dc61f4c1bffcad9b77d0f3aee5568d6dcdd10"
4,"0x395c3f208c09a9640880ae387331d7d58123bbd1","c0f075d2aa6510f75281b19f2c43771b99248f5784503344b21c590b8003419e"
5,"0x0d59b6bc0d014ee806230c4fee77e0c83bb6f453","0da749536ce1279d99663016428fe23a3799b842f982c6a1e81fa69cc0219a45"
6,"0xad17e413f8a47a07c8c7660f5c495b20176c59e0","994c6d8e93216ebd2f1e82662c00f3a7fb3e24f1245b4571791dc369f098bf20"
7,"0xa839ecc2305f433535eb1be00fc065ef728c61df","449fcc4846ec446e996653f3be7e81cf2f9c7df072ff2ece51e9f173928fb1cd"
```

Which outputs CSV: ID, public key (address), private key (here: unencrypted).

You can write them down. In general, I would recommend to encrypt them with a passphrase, but the output will be much more difficult to write down:

```
1,"0x5a594c44c194d9269025d07b9cf95e4b8fd767d2","U2FsdGVkX18TjcT/+fNBhHk1uPh1N72Vf3CLo/vkhor2+eKSEjeFbd13PbNcx78kwfwa0Gckv5yFjjQiR0qxyApPX6Buhs5e4IsYI90llPS0t75eJOz2b7qtPKlfX28T"
2,"0x052ce0c54dd7ec93fd513688fe954ae030889e6b","U2FsdGVkX1+XJEy6O2hw1N7PGnHtpQyrlLY+xD1J2X1TlgRqUB5gnQOS6rwi/mSEbdviLCjWKc3psQuV5UikS4wOmDunlWshGNTaoMIPj51Yh0KvfW22g6Evs1Z9COo3"
3,"0xbe8467807ea1374780d56a1bf9278fc1e1f5348a","U2FsdGVkX19SHpzNamqBl/JbmW2qzddPdQpIlKBadLstvlLtjmKI9YROxZlZEnHtK4mhPrKtTUWHGEF2sLAesVkBAqD71ORbWo6cEqa+C7pm4tkInuUTWWQVGEviNmGa"
4,"0xd903ff3313fdef8126b5f38c6775c0e34577ef33","U2FsdGVkX18V+us+TZ5ebawywwbW1eDtRjv8el6adTWcqf9Ag2nzWAtKlvZytCATEge4jzPZQaYJb7dZAMgjywGmxD63BPwZu7nc4hRzd+rWdVdT3NoyDE1WGJBa47Xp"
5,"0x425c6cd22c1673084d91bdc555115cf053a128a3","U2FsdGVkX1+BRDxxc4aDdYsdzjCDmHvBwiVp7GGFeBO2fc44pE+biTTaSz52Xrm9HhcwzHyQOxQc0KpRDckTiAV0VHb6MnfWcHKxlGTt5XzoMutZYrT6DWj8refcolp2"
6,"0x47bd738c482de1017c1bb44daed1174befe599f3","U2FsdGVkX1901zVkK+GEG1PNL5LWhAM/1EGGebUVKTBEqlEesgMliEb5bSGqQF+XbgmfefXjo/1lly8tPmEKz4vS4JNQU/m9gl9KMx/TADzz+mWbYj4WVo4KIqpaRdur"
7,"0x5600370a09691dea4e81735b86fb0b76182dcdee","U2FsdGVkX1+RwHwIB6SfPMAsoBGyWoz9QO72YY+J3hcfqWvlVnlW68jd5qAOaRVlZgnywpiKJmGjDCrTNR/ZiN0pHj3YlVN3+WdJ13qhFiMBxdLkrifblcNi+mXMCKm4"
```

A good alternative might a brain wallet, where you just have to remember the 20 words to generate the key pair. Here is [one generator](https://ryepdx.github.io/ethaddress.org/#/brainWallet). Here is [another](https://live.ether.camp/#seed) (click "get address").

But as always, test this with small amounts first!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do you import those bulk keys back into eth/geth?

Comment: Check [this question](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/465/87).

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you. That's almost perfect, but I still need to know a way to export the bulk keys of the accounts on geth... (wouldn't trust a thirdy party JS rng...)

Comment: Will parity's 'recovery phrase' also achieve this goal?

Comment: @dcorking yes, it does!