# Fail writing to state database. Bombing out

Tags: cpp-ethereum

Problems updating state on C++ ethereum on Ubuntu Linux 14.04

disks, /tmp have plenty of space.

`eth` was installed from ethereum ppa, is used intermittently to check balances and do transfers (mining runs elsewhere), has been updated from time to time, and had been working since 2015... until today.

```
eth --version
```

yields

```
eth version 1.2.4
eth network protocol version: 63
Client database version: 12041
Build: Linux/g++/Interpreter/Release
```

When starting `eth` normally, the error presents as numerous lines of

```
i <time> eth Put <hex> => <other hex>
X <time> eth Sleeping for <N> seconds, then retrying
```

When N reaches 9, eth exits:

```
  ✘  03:12:29.538|eth  Sleeping for 9 seconds, then retrying.
  ✘  03:12:38.538|eth  Fail writing to state database. Bombing out.
```

---

**EDIT:** I managed to rescue a small amount of stranded funds by following:

[Convert an eth key to a geth key](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/974/convert-an-eth-key-to-a-geth-key)

to move the keys from the c++ eth install to a geth-based mist wallet.

I am still willing to try any suggested fix to the c++ eth install; at this point the simplest thing is for me to delete it and start over.

---

How can I fix this?  Is there some way I can delete the local copy of the blockchain and let eth download it again, while maintaining account keys?

Comment: From the code, it looks like there should be a different error/warning string output before N is 9, along the lines of `Error writing to state database: xxxxxx`, where `xxxxx` might be something more interesting than "Bombing out". Is that the case?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Checking...

Comment: Now it is doing something different, but still failing: "Import Failure, Invalid Block Format, Guru Meditation #00000000.8e20de73".

Comment: This question is now a "problem that can no longer be reproduced"