# I can I restore Mist to reset master password?

Tags: mist, wallets, cpp-ethereum

I lost my Ethereum Wallet master password. I have all my account passwords. I've backed up my wallet, and application data. How do I restore Mist to create a new master password? How do I back up the blockchain so I do have to redownload it again?

Answer (score 1):

"It is NOT possible to access your account without a password and there is no forgot my password option here. Do not forget it."

http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/account-management.html

Comment: I didn't ask about a forgotten password options. My question was, Is the a way to just simple start over, and add my current accounts and data to a new Mist install, if so how do I do a fresh install to Mist?

Comment: You can. On the other hand if you don`t have your account`s password this account would be inaccessible (I mean you won`t be able to unlock it).

Comment: So I have the password to all of my wallet Accounts. Here's my problem: I lunch Mist, and click the Develop tab. Then I click Ethereum node, and switch from Geth, to Eth. Mist then ask me to enter Master Password. I don't remember setting up a password for this, and I tried leaving it blank still doesn't work. If I reinstall Mist would I be able to create a new Master Password, and load my wallets addresses again? I understand that if I didn't have the wallet passwords I wouldn't be able to retrieve them.

Comment: As I know accounts are not transferrable between geth and eth. If you switching to eth in Mist you just may to create new accounts or convert with undocumented way. http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/974/convert-an-eth-key-to-a-geth-key