# Ethereum Vanity Address generators

Tags: wallets, accounts, addresses

Are there **any** Ethereum vanity address generators **available** other than:

- [Vanityreum](https://github.com/antonio-fr/Vanityreum) (python)
- [Vanieth](https://github.com/makevoid/vanieth) (go)

Which is the fastest? Can they be optimized further?

What is the **use-case** of vanity addresses compared to normal addresses?

Comment: Your question is more an answer :) Maybe rephrase the question and consider adding also an own answer to this thread...

Comment: I didn't want to answer my own question, and maybe accept it, that is a bit lame, isn't it?

Comment: [It is okay to answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). It is even encouraged. Even now you could answer it. Wait with accepting for some more days, maybe more answers will follow.

Comment: To me, doing that, it looks a bit like reputation-farming, especially if you create the question and answer straight away. Also I don't know how to optimize a vanity address generator (I guess something can be done to the hash function to narrow it after each run but I don't know exactly what/how) and I would like to know the answer :). But if nobody puts another answer I'll try to, thanks.

Comment: Reputation farmin is perfectly fine as long as you generate high quality content. We need 10 users with 2k+ reputation to graduate the site.

Comment: An ICAP address may be vanity, [suggested by its author](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/03/02/gavs-ethereum-d%CE%BEv-update-v/#comment-1883944597)

Comment: Perhaps the use-case question can be asked separately?  Other generators and notes about them could be added to the community wiki?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a community wiki of vanity address generators, sorted by name.

## NOTE !

- You should always check that you can use your newly generated addresses before sending any significant amount of ethers to these addresses.
- You could send a small amount of ethers to your newly generated address, then move a small portion of these ethers from your newly generated address to another address.
- You could cross-check your generated address against an air-gapped (if you are paranoid) installation of https://www.myetherwallet.com/. `@tayvano` is one of the authors.
- Better still cross-check your generated address by importing your newly generated private key into `geth` (see [How to import a plain private key into geth or Mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth-or-mist)).

---

## Vanity Address Generators

### ethaddress.org

Download from [ethaddress.org](https://github.com/ryepdx/ethaddress.org) or run from the Internet on your web browser from https://ryepdx.github.io/ethaddress.org/. `@ryepdx` is the author.

- This is a full paper wallet generator that includes a **bulk** vanity generator
- It is safer to download the [ethaddress.org - master.zip](https://github.com/ryepdx/ethaddress.org/archive/master.zip) from github, copy the package to an air-gapped computer (if you are paranoid), unzip the files and browse index.html.
- There was a bug [#19](https://github.com/ryepdx/ethaddress.org/issues/19) in the address generation due to bug in the downstream ethereumjs-tx dependency, but this is now fixed. If you have downloaded this package prior to 03/03/2016, please re-download the package.

### ethaddrgen

[Ethaddrgen](https://github.com/Limeth/ethaddrgen) is a multicore command line utility written in Rust for generating Ethereum vanity addresses. It includes support for **pattern lists, regexp, continuous results, and more**.

### Ethereum Vanity

[Ethereum Vanity](https://github.com/whitj00/ethereum-vanity) - Written in JavaScript

### Vanieth

[Vanieth](https://github.com/makevoid/vanieth) - Written in Go

### Vanityreum

[Vanityreum](https://github.com/antonio-fr/Vanityreum) - Written in Python

### Vanity-ETH

[Vanity-ETH](https://bokub.github.io/vanity-eth/) is an ETH vanity address generator that runs in your web browser.

- It can save your generated address into a password encrypted JSON/UTC keystore file compatible with MyEtherWallet, MetaMask, Mist, geth...
- I runs from any computer, no software needed other than a web browser
- You can download a build and make it work completely offline if you're paranoid

---

## Vanity Identicon Generators

### Ethereum Vanity Identicon Generator

The [Ethereum Vanity Identicon Generator](http://www.codywatts.com/projects/ethereum-vanity-identicon-generator) is a JavaScript-based generator which can be run from your web browser. [Cody Watts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/4654/cody) is the author.

- Although it can be used to generate vanity addresses, its primary purpose is to generate addresses which have unusual or distinctive [identicons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon).
- Identicons can be filtered by symmetry, number of colors, contrast-ratio and color scheme.

Comment: Pro tip: When testing the address to make sure it really works, it's good enough to send ETH on a testnet, such as Ropsten. No need to send real ETH in these times of high gas prices.

Comment: !!!!!!! 
Be aware that Profanity just disclosed a vulnerability, so avoid that one! See: https://github.com/johguse/profanity

Answer (score 4):

Whit Jackson made one that appears to be made using HTML/Javascript ([GitHub link](https://github.com/whitj00/ethereum-vanity)). He also had a website where you could generate the addresses client side, but it [appears to be down now](https://whitjack.me/ethereum-vanity/).

Answer (score 0):

## Vanitygen Plus Plus

There is another very fast (support GPU) vanity address generator, support BTC/ETH/etc. See: https://github.com/10gic/vanitygen-plusplus

Answer (score 0):

I developed simple vanity address generator which is working as Vue js PWA web app on github-pages here: https://gkucmierz.github.io/vanity-eth/

Here is the source code:
https://github.com/gkucmierz/vanity-eth

Right now it is using few (depending how much cores it detects) workers on CPU, but probably it is possible to also implement mining it on GPU using https://www.w3.org/TR/webgpu

[image]