# Client Side JavaScript Ethereum Address Generation?

Tags: addresses, javascript, offline, name-registrar

I would like to generate Ethereum addresses clientside with JavaScript, what is the best way to go about doing this? 
Also, I read that dual Eth-Bitcoin addresses are now possible, and there are  many open source clientside Bitcoin address generators available, it possible to generate Bitcoin Addresses and use them with Ethereum?

Comment: Please separate these two questions into separate ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can e.g. use [Keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum) to create Ethereum addresses from Javascript:

```
var params = { keyBytes: 32, ivBytes: 16 };
var dk = keythereum.create(params);
var keyDump = keythereum.dump("password123", dk.privateKey, dk.salt, dk.iv);
var address = keyDump.address;
```

They have a node module and a browser version.

Keep in mind though that you'll just see that address in a public blockchain explorer once you sent some Ether to it.