# How to recover presale wallet password from mnemonics

Tags: wallets, presale, recovery, password

I have the following stored in my secure password manager from the presale:

- A 40-character hexadecimal address
- A 64-character hexadecimal private key
- A list of 24 mnemonic words
- Something I called "ethereum purchase password", a 16-character string with numbers, letters and punctuation characters.
- A json file containing my wallet

I'm trying to import this json file into [ethereum wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.5.1), and it asks for a password. When I use my "ethereum purchase password," it says the password is wrong. Not sure what the problem is, but I assume I should be able to recover my password from the mnemonic words. How do I do this?

Comment: I tried importing my wallet with geth and the same password, and I think it may have worked. At any rate, it did not report any errors, though I'm not sure it did anything.

Comment: OK, so I've figured out that the error is just some problem with the ethereum wallet app, but it would still be nice to know how to recover a password from the mnemonic words.

Answer (score 4):

Are you aware of the bug in the Mist wallet? It is exactly what you explained or did I misunderstand? If you are confident you are entering the correct pass then its likely the bug. users reported a bug, and devs confirmed that in some cases entering the correct password will fail stating wrong PW when its actually correct. You could use the Kraken json converter that would put the coins online and then send directly to your local wallet. I personally don't leave any coins other than what I am actively trading at that moment online anymore since the Cryptsy disaster. Hope this helps, search for password bug and you will see posts from people much smarter than me :) Good luck

Comment: Oops, just saw you figured it out already. not sure why I didn't see that before. Sorry

Comment: Thanks tageeboy. I'd still like to know how to recover a password with mnemonics, if someone knows that.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the right private key (and from the looks of being 64 hex characters or 32 bytes it seems right), then you do not need anything else.

Just import that into any client and you should be good to go. See this question on how to do it: [How to import a plain private key into geth or Mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth)

Comment: I was able to import my wallet. But it would still be nice to explain to people how to recover their password from the mnemonics that the ethereum presale gave, so I left the question up.