# Importing paper wallet using geth gives encoding error

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, import

Importing from a paper wallet(myetherwallet) gives:

Could not create the account: encoding/hex: invalid byte: U+007B '{'

I am using the private unencrypted key.

go 1.5.3,
Geth 1.3.5,
Waller 0.5.1,

Comment: You don't say how the paper wallet was created was it MyEtherWallet.com? If you have the private key you can just import it as described here http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth/466#466

Answer (score 2):

I had saved the file in rtf , I opened a file using vi and saved that.
This worked , so it seems to be a formatting error.

Comment: rtf is rich text so there are erroneous character and font sizes and colors in there. Saving it as. txt would fix the problem as well, which is essentially what you did.