# How can I import accounts created by quorumwallet into Ethereum Wallet Mist?

Tags: mist, wallets, accounts, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I created an Ethereum address using quorumwallet.com. How can I manually import it to Mist Wallet so I can transact using Mist?

Comment: Have you created a contract or a contract generated the address for you?

Comment: The contract asked for my key phrases and then generated the account for me on the Blockchain

Comment: I don't fully understand. Can you tell the Dapp or your created address?

Comment: My account was created by a Dapp **quorumwallet.com** [link](http://quorumwallet.com/) that asked me to type my key phrase, then the quorumwallet Smart Contract sent it to the blockchain. This account is mine, but the Quorumwallet Smart Contract created it for me. I just want to integrate it on my Mist Wallet.  thanks

Answer (score 5):

You will need to:

1. Recover the private key to the account as described in [Quorum Wallet FAQ](http://quorumwallet.com/faq#account).

   ```
   seed = String(passphrase) + String(userid);
   privatekey = PBKDF2(seed, seed, 2000, 32, 'sha256');
   ```
2. [Import the plain private key to Ethereum Wallet / geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth).

Comment: Hi, I'm using `ethereumjs/keythereum` to try to create my privatekey with no luck,  this are the params I'm using `var params = { keyBytes: 32, ivBytes: 16, pbkdf2: {
              c: 2000,
              dklen: 32,
              hash: "sha256"
            } 
        };` and the code: `var dk = keythereum.create(params, this.fullName);
    var key = keythereum.dump(this.fullName, dk.privateKey, dk.salt, dk.iv);
    this.ethAccount = JSON.stringify(key);`, or can you suggest other way to do it? Thx!

Comment: You should add a new question about that to reach bigger audience. I am not familiar with ethereumjs.

Comment: Here is the new question [How can I generate a V3 of the Ethereum wallet file format in js, from strings: 'Passphrase' and 'Email or username' required by Quorumwallet?] (http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/how-can-i-generate-a-v3-of-the-ethereum-wallet-file-format-in-js-from-two-strin)