# How can I generate a V3 of the Ethereum wallet file format in js, from strings: 'Passphrase' and 'Email or username' required by Quorumwallet?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, accounts, brain-wallets

[Quorum Wallet](https://quorumwallet.com/faq) prompts for a Passphrase and a Email or username to generate the account.

[image: Quorumwallet account set up]

On the FAQs there is a description of the algorithm to generate the account:

> What is the algorithm used to create my account?
>
> It is fairly simple:
>
> seed = String(passphrase) + String(userid); privatekey = PBKDF2(seed,
>   seed, 2000, 32, 'sha256');

How can I generate the Version 3 of the Ethereum wallet format file using Javascript?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet) library to create a wallet file from your raw private key, or directly from your Quorum wallet info:

```
var ethJS = require('ethereumjs-wallet');
var thirdparty = require('ethereumjs-wallet/thirdparty');
var wallet = thirdparty.fromQuorumWallet(passphrase, userid);
var v3 = toV3(password, [options]);
```

Comment: can you please detail the required options of the function 'toV3' as proposed by the Quorum FAQ?