# How get Ethereum address using phrase only in Android

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, addresses, web3j, android

I want to get Etherum address and private key by adding **Phrase (or Password)** everytime.
I tried by following many gihub code.It gives different private key everytime.
In Web3j, I found it is based on file.

I want to make a programme in such a way that it will create same wallet again (Based on password or phrase).

Is there any way.If yes than please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to make a programme in such a way that it will create same
>   wallet again (Based on password or phrase).

This is mostly called seed.

Refer to this answer :
[How to generate Private key, public key and address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39384/how-to-generate-private-key-public-key-and-address)

```
const bip39 = require('bip39');
const hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey');

const mnemonic = '..';
const hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic));
const path = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/0";
const wallet = hdwallet.derivePath(path).getWallet();
const address = `0x${wallet.getAddress().toString('hex')}`;

console.log(`Address: ${address}`);
```

Some good source for testing :

https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39

https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

Comment: I asked for Android. Please check title of the question

Comment: I've checked. Since you can use almost every language in every platform better do distinction as; Android is name of OS and Java is name of language. Better use (Android/Java) in your question and use tags like Java, ethereumj, web3j, etc.. I believe you have answer here : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41072/generate-private-key-and-address-using-web3j and there : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6673/generating-ethereum-private-key-public-key-on-mobile-android-java

Comment: It works but everytime creates new wallet , new address and private key.

Comment: Did you try to change this line "String seed = UUID.randomUUID().toString();" in first link. You need to provide your seed word.