# How to import a plain private key into Parity?

Tags: accounts, parity, private-key, import

Basically the parity version of [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth-or-mist).

Can Parity import raw private keys or Geth keystore files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to remember just copying them into .local/share/io...../keys.  The keys I had were generated on myetherwallet though, not geth.  Or depending on how you installed, it might be ~/.parity/keys.

I think there is also an "import" function in the Parity UI that is accessible at port 8180.  So open a browser to 127.0.0.1:8180 on a computer that is running Parity.)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to stone.212's answer, here is another way:

Simply follow the instructions to import a private key into Geth, and then copy your keystore file into Parity's keys folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a command-line option:

```
parity account import [path to geth keystore file]
```