# Convert a Bitcoin private key into an Ethereum address

Tags: addresses, private-key, bitcoin

I'm currently using the lightwallet.js for ethereum and it seems to only accept a mnemonic seed to generate an ethereum address. I want to be able to use my Bitcoin private key to generate an ethereum address. I'm able to generate a bitcoin private key using bitcoinjs library, but I can't seem to figure out how I can do this with ethereum using a bitcoin private key. Is there a specific library I need to use?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated

Comment: I thinks is not a good decision use your private key for this, cause this will be a security hole in the future, if some one can revert the process he can obtain your bitcoin private key and this is very dangerous if you have money inside...

Comment: @Gawey Your public key is already exposed in bitcoin, though..no?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude yes ofc, but the public key not the private key... there is the problem here, he want use the private key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A private key in both bitcoin and ethereum is simply a random 256 bit number (actually a number between 0 and the order of the secp256k1 curve, but that's not really important).

If you can get your raw bitcoin public key, i.e.something like a random hex string of length 64, then it can be used directly as a raw ETH private key in any library or client.

For example, to import it into geth just use

```
geth account import <(my_privkey)
```

for parity see [How to import a plain private key into Parity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16627/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-parity)

To simply derive an address from the key in JS, you can use the [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum) library or [ethereumjs-util](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/master/docs/index.md#privatetopublic)

You can even use openssl, see https://kobl.one/blog/create-full-ethereum-keypair-and-address/

Answer (score 0):

Putting a bitcoin private key into my ether wallet as a private key will open an Ethereum wallet

I’m not sure how this works

This also makes a few valid Ethereum addresses

https://shiftcrypto.ch/backup