# paper wallet with only private and public keys

Tags: wallets

How do i tranfer from paper wallet .i only have the public and private keys .the wallet is from the start of the year at close to $280 now its close to$2400 and scared of loosing .how do i get it out o fpaper wallet please help.

Comment: Look around https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth-or-mist