# Can't transfer Alt Coins on Parity

Tags: parity

when I attempt to transfer my EOS or SNT from my parity wallet to any other wallet or exchange.. is this normal or is there any advice on how I can go about doing that?

I believe that my private key was stolen in an airdrop scam and now I need to move the coins out of parity. It says that my balance is not available but clearly shows the coin in the wallet.

Comment: If you have your private key/UTC file you can use MyEtherWallet to transfer your tokens, they have support for EOS and SNT tokens.

Comment: Are you fully synchronized?

Answer (score 1):

Import your private key to the Ethereum Wallet and transfer from there.

Refer to this for importing your private key: [How to import a plain private key into geth or Mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth-or-mist)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can transfer any Token like EOS or SNT using Parity like any normal ETH transaction.

Just select the token you wish to transfer from the drop-down in the Transaction view and proceed as normal. Note, you need ETH in your account to cover the gas costs.