# Troubles importing mist wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, wallets, import

I am currently attempting to import my old wallet onto a new pc in order to be able to transfer the 2 ethereums that I have stored on it onto an exchange, but can't for the life of me figure out how to do so.

I have tried the command promt fix recommended here : [How to import a plain private key into geth or Mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth-or-mist?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But I got the following,

> 'geth' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable
>   program or batch file.

Is it referring to a command prompt inside mist that I'm not aware of? The one I used is the regular old ms command promp. If so where is this prompt located?

I have access to both my public and private key, the folder called keystore, and the password that I created for the account. What I don't have is any programming knowledge to speak of.

So if someone could please, explain, in laymans terms, a way for me to either import my wallet, or transfer my ether from the wallet to the exchange without accessing it through mist, that would be very much appreciated.

- old wallet address : `0xf9FA047336bCfE8cC290310423c4CC509Fc99765` (where my ether is located)
- new wallet address (etherbase account created upon download of mist onto new pc, which i currently have access to): `0xc5F77607AA3283Bbb60150f7F8E3FcEfBdaEB1F7`

Thank you for your time, and for helping out a hapless noob who dipped his head in too deep!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

> The one I used is the regular old ms command prompt

You have to use the *regular old ms command prompt* as you have done already.

The Error,

> 'geth' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable
>   program or batch file

is because you haven't set the environmental variable path correctly. set the path variable and reopen the command prompt. Follow [this tutorial](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/) to learn how to fix this issue in general.