# ERC20 Ropsten - how do I view the token balance?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ropsten, etherscan, crowdsale

I've published crowdsale contract to the Ropsten test network and it is located here: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x5b15b8f8238b9ec9e9c50e9f9bfcee6073349a96

I've struggled with ABI-encoded constructor parameters, so instead I've hardcoded the initial values directly into the code - you can see **Contract Source Code Verified**.

I've sent `0.01535` test ETH to the contract address *(it was 15:35 my time and I wanted to keep track)* and now I would like to see tokens being distributed.

[image]

I put the token address into the https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token-search and:

```
Sorry! We were unable to locate any valid Token Transfer Events for Contract 0x9c7214181b38c6421447b685dfceb7179574d155. If you are sure this is a contract that confirms to the ERC20 Token standard then please try again once a valid transfer has been made

Token Attributes Found: 
 totalSupply = 15350000000000000000
 name = {not detected} 
 symbol = {not detected} 
 decimals = {not detected}
```

Had a quick look at ERC20 standard and what methods are required: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

I based my code on https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6 so I would imagine these methods are implemented.

For someone reason token search does not detect ERC20 - what shall I do to make it work?

---

**EDIT/UPDATE:** A little bit of yak shaving, bike shedding here or there - I'm letting you know I'm learning here and I'm doing my best.

> If you are sure this is a contract that confirms to the ERC20 Token standard then please try again once a valid transfer has been made

I'm sure it is ERC20 token. Added it to metamask and MEW, both are showing the balance.

[image]

[image]

A friend advised me to interact with the contract and do the token transfer, that actually makes sense: *"please try again once a valid transfer has been made"*

Importing private key into Ethereum Wallet: [How to import a plain private key into geth or Mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth-or-mist)

`geth account import Desktop/priv.txt
WARN [09-12|02:24:53] No etherbase set and no accounts found as default
Your new account is locked with a password. Please give a password. Do not forget this password.
Passphrase:
Repeat passphrase:
Address: {426cdad20cbd33ea0bf0338c47239b9778a61fe2}`

I do see the account though:
[image]

I think what I may want to do, is to deploy the contract from scratch from Ethereum Wallet, then do the token transfer, then see if it appears on Etherscan.

Comment: Did you try to publish the source code of your token contract? It is missing, perhaps is that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question.

In my case - when deploying contract there were two contracts deployed at the same time.

`Crowdsale` contract and `Token` contract. Guess what? For token tracker I was putting crowdsale contract...

I was too embarrassed to admit what I want to do, now please allow me to be forgiven.

Answer (score 1):

You can see your tokens on etherscan or other platforms. [Here](https://ethereum-balance.com/) for example you can see it also with the current worth of the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

```
var contract = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./contract.json', 'utf8'));
var Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contract, cont_addr);

Contract.methods.balanceOf('token_address').call().then(function(res){
  console.log("Token Balance:::",res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that etherscan is not going to show your contract as token unless you make at least one transfer and emit an event for it as it is described in ERC20 standard.

If you are sure that you have a correct ERC20 token deployed then you can change your etherscan url to force it to threat as token.

The only difference between showing your contract as a token or normal contract is in URL. This is an example for EOS Token.

[https://etherscan.io/**address**/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0](https://etherscan.io/address/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0)

[https://etherscan.io/**token**/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0](https://etherscan.io/token/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0)

Comment: See the accepted answer by myself. Figured it out :)