# Where are keystore of testrpc?

Tags: testrpc

I am puzzled that where are the keystor files of default 10 accounts testrpc provides?

I start `testrpc --db ./data`

I can see account default accounts:

## Available Accounts

(0) 0x32fc58d738e05b95fd38149307aa6d4f0c6f2e9a
(1) 0xca656349efa15f9eaff70ad0fb385974690c4f66

## Private Keys

(0) 39ae40325da1a15ee8b726e091ed36f65cd1421118d468d73f28da3f0e3da8ad
(1) 1119f02b97540a17640afa07f7452989e4ee7281a97b5d3ba55fb02078042a6c

like these...

I can't find anything in keystore folder for these accounts.

I want to IMPORT All these Accounts in METAMASK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the accounts via

```
--acctKeys <path to file>  (saves generated accounts and private keys as JSON object in specified file)
```

but you'll not be able to import this file to Metamask. Hence, you'll have to copy&paste the private keys as string to Metamask.

Alternatively, you could parse this json file and import it to geth like described in this post here: "[How to import a plain private key into geth or Mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth-or-mist)". After that you'll have the keystore files, which you can import to Metamask.

Comment: Exactly I wanted!